# App works perfectly in debug mode but not in release mode- flutter run --release

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

My app is working perfectly in debug mode but not in release mode. it is gone froze for a while and all views are not perfectly displaying in release mode and console shows 'Another exception was thrown: Instance of'DiagnosticsProperty' is there any solution?

Comment: run the app with flutter run -v and post the output to have more information

Comment: again console shows this
[        ] I/flutter (10249): Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'

Comment: It is really hard to help if you give so little information

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. Later, the debug version repeated the error. After solving the problem, the release version can be used. The reason for my problem is that the data is empty under abnormal conditions, which is for reference only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing internet then you should add internet permission in main app manifest. By default, it's not there. So if you missed that check now.